# Sort classes in dependency order (NDepend)

Tags: c#, ndepend

I'm new to NDepend and just getting my feet wet. I'm able to create a class dependency graph using the following simple query:

```
from t in Application.Types
// remove compiler generated classes
where !t.FullName.Contains(">")
// sort by dependency count
orderby t.TypesUsed.Count()
select new { t, t.TypesUsed }
```

I'm trying to build an ordered list of classes such that the first items in the list do not have dependencies other than system types. As we progress through the list, each type should only have dependencies that appear before it in the list. I realize that in cases with cyclical dependencies this is not possible, but I'd like to at least get them into a more correct order than simply ordering by the dependency count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a but tricky but feasible. This CQLinq code query uses the magic of the NDepend.API method [FillIterative()](https://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ExtensionMethodsHelpers~FillIterative.html).

```
// The call FillIterative() will fill hashSet with types already processed
let hashSet = new HashSet<IType>()

let fillHashSetWithTypesFunc = new Func<IEnumerable<IType>, bool>(types => types.All(t => hashSet.Add(t)))

let metric = ThirdParty.Types.FillIterative(
   types => 
      // Use a ternary operator to invoke fillHashSetWithTypesFunc() that always return true,
      fillHashSetWithTypesFunc(types) ?
         // Select t when hashSet contains all t.TypesUsed
         Application.Types.Where(t => t.TypesUsed.Intersect(hashSet).Count() == t.TypesUsed.Count()) :
         // new IType[0] is never invoqued coz fillHashSetWithTypesFunc() always returns true
         new IType[0])

from val in metric 
where val.Value > 0  // Don't show third-party types
orderby val.Value ascending
select new { val.CodeElement, 
   (val.CodeElement as IType).Level, 
   val.Value, 
   (val.CodeElement as IType).TypesUsed }
```

Types involved in a cycle are not matched.

The result assigns a value to each type matched:

- (1) are types only using third-party types
- (2) are types using third-party and types in (1)
- (3) ...

Interestingly enough the metric [IType.Level](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/code-metrics#Level) provides exactly that measure and answers your question. But it is more fun to re-write it with a code query. Same could be done with namespaces (that also have the Level metric), assemblies and methods.

[image: Level metric applied on type]